# How to mount the "root" file system of a Windows Samba Share with cifs?

Tags: samba, cifs

Is it possible to mount the "root" of a Windows Samba Share?
I have successfully mounted a specific Samba share with this:

```
mount.cifs //server/share /mnt -o username=blub
```

What I would like to mount is the overview of all accessible shares, which Windows shows if you enter `\\server` in the Explorer.

But mounting like this:

```
mount.cifs //server /mnt --verbose -o username=blub
```

fails with:

```
Password for blub@//server:  ********
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=172.16.83.13,unc=\\server\,user=blub,prefixpath=mnt,pass=********
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Reading the manpage did not lead me to anything.
Is it even possible to do such things with CIFS?
I have neither read that this specific thing is impossible or that it should be possible.
All examples are just mounting `\\server\share` and not the share overview.

I am using Gentoo Linux with cifs-utils 6.1, Kernel 3.18.7.

Comment: AFAIK you need to mount each share separately, as each share may have its own restrictions and allowed users. The list can be obtained with `smbclient -L ...`, if that's what you're after. You can't mount the "root" of multiple NFS exports either.

Comment: @wurtel well, actually, with NFSv4 you can, but that's beside the point.

Comment: Well, that's a pity. I thought this is quite a nice thing, but then I will mount each share separately. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: @wurtel I hate to see questions languish without an answer so I've copied your comment as an answer (Community Wiki).

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually possible. You need to mount each share separately, as each share may have its own restrictions and allowed users. The list can be obtained with `smbclient -L ...`